# Making predictions with a TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow

I followed the given mnist tutorials and was able to train a model and evaluate its accuracy. However, the tutorials don't show how to make predictions given a model. I'm not interested in accuracy, I just want to use the model to predict a new example and in the output see all the results (labels), each with its assigned score (sorted or not).

Comment: I made a repository where you can draw numbers and test the model with your own data. https://github.com/EddieOne/mnist-live-test It doesn't come with instructions. I did however make a video with a high level overview. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pudJU-cDkMo

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In the "[Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros)" example, see this line:

> We can now implement our regression model. It only takes one line! We
>   multiply the vectorized input images x by the weight matrix W, add the
>   bias b, and compute the softmax probabilities that are assigned to
>   each class.
>
> ```
> y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
> ```

Just pull on node y and you'll have what you want.

```
feed_dict = {x: [your_image]}
classification = tf.run(y, feed_dict)
print classification
```

This applies to just about any model you create - you'll have computed the prediction probabilities as one of the last steps before computing the loss.

Comment: When testing this suggestion on the convnet example (with `y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2) ` I get `Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float`, for the simple softmax example it works fine. Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: I can answer my own comment: The convnet example has an additional variable in the feed_dict, I missed to add that. In this case the feed_dict should look like this: `feed_dict = {x: [your_image], keep_prob:1.0}`

Comment: The output of your code will be some thing like [False  True False ...,  True False  True], but i want to convert this into [3  1 3 ...,  1 5  1], which incorrect class labels instead of False. how can we able to get that label that is wrongly classified instead of false?

Comment: `tf.run()` seems to have been removed, but `y.eval(feed_dict)` worked for me.

Comment: a more complete thought of this question, can be found here,
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/97. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @astromme I know it's not very ok to do so and you might flag me but I'm really really need help with tensor flow and ill delete this comment as soon you'll see it. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104783/making-predictions-with-tensorflow), Thanks

Comment: Hi @DanielZakrisson I would like your help too please.

Comment: Because it is incomplete, there will be errors using the accepted answer. You also need to write code to get a session, initialize variables, etc.

Answer (score 16):

As @dga suggested, you need to run your new instance of the data though your already predicted model.

Here is an example:

Assume you went though the first tutorial and calculated the accuracy of your model (the model is this: `y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)`). Now you grab your model and apply the new data point to it. In the following code I calculate the vector, getting the position of the maximum value. Show the image and print that maximum position.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randint
num = randint(0, mnist.test.images.shape[0])
img = mnist.test.images[num]

classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [img]})
plt.imshow(img.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
print 'NN predicted', classification[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: Suppose you have built a Keras Model as shown below:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then Train and Evaluate the Model using the below code:

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
```

After that, if you want to predict the class of a particular image, you can do it using the below code:

```
predictions_single = model.predict(img)
```

If you want to predict the classes of a set of Images, you can use the below code:

```
predictions = model.predict(new_images)
```

where `new_images` is an Array of Images.

For more information, refer this [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification).

Answer (score 2):

The question is specifically about the [Google MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), which defines a predictor but doesn't apply it.   Using guidance from [Jonathan Hui's TensorFlow Estimator blog post](https://jhui.github.io/2017/03/14/TensorFlow-Estimator/), here is code which exactly fits the Google tutorial and does predictions:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

images = mnist.test.images[0:10]

predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x":images},
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)

mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)

for image,p in zip(images,mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)):
    print(np.argmax(p['probabilities']))
    plt.imshow(image.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```