# Print Tensor Value

Tags: tensorflow

Code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py

I want to be able to see/print/display tensor content ( tensor ***y***, - (image, trained label) i.e. x, y pairs for each batch  ), as well as the final result.

For example in:

for i in range(1000):

batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

# here should be a line to print/eval/sess.run learned x, y pair

Comment: None of cases in existing print tensor value thread quoted above is a close match. 
The problem was how to print/see tensor value that is fed via placeholder. That requires special syntax which I had a problem with.
Steven below has great answer.

Comment: Question was actually similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like

```
print(sess.run([y],feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))
```

This will print out y.  You can also store the variable and then interact with it as you would a numpy array.

```
y_val = sess.run([y],feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Note you should change the name to y_val instead of y as setting y = sess.run([y]...) will overwrite the tensorflow variable y and crash the second time around.

Comment: Thank you Steven, this exactly solved it.
Much appreciated !