# How to predict using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

This is a newbie question for the tensorflow experts:

I reading lot of data from power transformer connected to an array of solar panels using arduinos, my question is can I use tensorflow to predict the power generation in future.

I am completely new to tensorflow, if can point me to something similar I can start with that or any github repo which is doing similar predictive modeling.

Edit: Kyle pointed me to the MNIST data, which I believe is a Image Dataset. Again, not sure if tensorflow is the right computation library for this problem or does it only work on Image datasets?

thanks, Rajesh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making predictions with a TensorFlow model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model)

Answer (score 2):

Surely you can use tensorflow to solve your problem.

> TensorFlow™ is an open source software library for numerical
>   computation using data flow graphs.

So it works not only on Image dataset but also others. Don't worry about this.

And about prediction, first you need to train a model(such as linear regression) on you dataset, then predict. The tutorial code can be found in [tensorflow homepage](https://www.tensorflow.org) .

Get your hand dirty, you will find it works on your dataset.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use TensorFlow to predict time series. There are plenty of examples out there, [like this one](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-do-time-series-prediction-using-rnns-and-tensorflow-and-cloud-ml-engine-2ad2eeb189e8). And [this is a really interesting one on using RNN to predict basketball trajectories](https://github.com/RobRomijnders/RNN_basketball).

In general, TF is a very flexible platform for solving problems with machine learning. You can create any kind of network you can think of in it, and train that network to act as a model for your process. Depending on what kind of costs you define and how you train it, you can build a network to classify data into categories, predict a time series forward a number of steps, and other cool stuff.

There is, sadly, no short answer for how to do this, but that's just because the possibilities are endless! Have fun!