# How to predict unlabeled images in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been going through several Tensorflow tutorials and have not seen anything on using a model after it's been trained/tested with. I looked through stackoverflow and found a few solutions that aren't working for me like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model)

So I'm using the code [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py) with the exception that I altered the code so I could try running predictions afterwards instead of the session closing. For the prediction I'm just using a test sample, but trying to work it out without giving a label. I want to see what class is predicted.

```
# Launch the graph
#with tf.Session() as sess:
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
step = 1
# Keep training until reach max iterations
while step * batch_size < training_iters:
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    # Run optimization op (backprop)
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                               keep_prob: dropout})
    if step % display_step == 0:
        # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
        loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                      y: batch_y,
                                                      keep_prob: 1.})
        print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
          "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
          "{:.5f}".format(acc))
    step += 1
print("Optimization Finished!")

# Calculate accuracy for 256 mnist test images
print("Testing Accuracy:", \
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                  y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                  keep_prob: 1.}))
```

From the stack overflow page I listed above I should be able to do something like this

```
print(tf.run(pred, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]}))
```

Though it looks like this has been removed as tensorflow is saying there is not run function. A comment in that same page suggested to do this

```
print(pred.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]}))
```

but I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is   registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to     `eval(session=sess)`
```

With this I found I needed to run what was stated above but I'm getting an issue with the tensor being the incorrect size

```
with sess.as_default():
    print(pred.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]}))

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (784,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'
```

So from here it looks like the data is not aligned correctly? I've tried using reshape with no success. If anyone could point me into the right direction so I can figure out how to actual use my model for applications that would be great.

EDIT: Here's a simpler program. I'm having the same issue

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for i in range(1000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
y.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]})
```

I'm getting the same issue as above

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (784,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to your notebook is a local link, so no one else can see it.  Also, you are missing some code.  Where is "y" defined?

All you need to do is to evaluate y, e.g.: y.eval(feed_dict={x: NEW_DATA})

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the link. I'll edit my post with all of the code.

Comment: I made an edit to show a smaller example. I'm taking the y output and using eval as you stated. Now I'm getting an output, though I'm not sure what the values are.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Got the eval working. My issue was not recognizing the outputs represented the classes, and the highest value is the most probably. I'm going to find out how to turn that into a 0 - 1 probability. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  The output of your model is a log odds, so I think you can convert it to a probability between 0 and 1 with a softmax function: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax

Comment: That did the trick! Just need to format it in non-scientific notation and I'm happy. Thanks for the help!