# How can I generate output predictions in Tensorflow just like model.predict in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, ipython, keras

Keras has model.predict which generates output predictions for the input samples. I am looking for this in tensorflow but cannot seem to find it or code it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making predictions with a TensorFlow model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.contrib.Keras to get same behavior.