# Making predictions with Tensorflow model on new data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to TensorFlow and I am trying to model a two layer fully-connected neural network for regression in TensorFlow. The answer in the following StackOverflow discussion shows how to make predictions with a single layer neural network model. However, I feel this approach will become inefficient with more layers.

[Making predictions with a TensorFlow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711556/making-predictions-with-a-tensorflow-model)

Could anyone please let me know, how I can make predictions with my TensorFlow model?
I have defined my network as shown below:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])

weights_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]))
weights_h2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]))
weights_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_output]))

bias_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1]))
bias_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_output]))


# Hidden layer with RELU activation
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights_h1), bias_b1)
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
# Hidden layer with RELU activation
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights_h2), bias_b2)
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
# Output layer with linear activation
out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights_out), bias_out)
```

Using the following command, I can train my neural network model.

`_, training_error = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})`

Comment: What makes you think it will be inefficient? Do you want to make predictions in an online way (one image at a time) or in batches over lots of images?

Comment: @thertweck The following representation was shown in the other post to make predictions on new data:  
`y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)                        
feed_dict = {x: [your_image]}
classification = tf.run(y, feed_dict)`. 
However, for a two or more layered model, this representation could be inefficient, as multiple layers will be written in a single line of code. I am just wondering if there are other ways to feed in data into the model? I am trying to make predictions with new data that is not in the training dataset.

Comment: There is of course a performance impact of having more layers since the additional layers require computation too. Nevertheless this has nothing to do with feed_dict. You do not have to run the layers separately - you would still call sess.run() only once (even with more than one layer). If you are bothered by feed_dict in general you might want to use input pipelines or the new Dataset API in tf.contrib.data, that's much faster then using feed_dict.